# Is it possible to have generic decorators in TypeScript that could be chained per their input/output types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, finagle

For some of our integrations we have rather "templatized" implementations in our code base which can be conveniently put into the "pipe and filter" pattern IMHO.

The "components" can be made to look like the following type(s):

```
class Component1<In, Out, Xin, Xout>
class Component2<Xin, Xout, Yin, Yout>
class Component3<Yin, Yout> // only has 2 params but could be <Yin, Yout, None, None> for a custom 'None' type
```

The idea is to have something to allow these to be "chained" to allow for something like this:

```
const c1 = new Component1<A,B,C,D>(...) //perhaps pass the param types in constructor? Other options?
const c2 = new Component2<C,D,E,F>(...)
const c3 = new Component3<E,F, None, None>(...)

const chain = c1.andThen(c2).andThen(c3) // The "last" item in the chain would "always" be a component of type <X,Y, None, None>

chain.run() // Not sure if this is needed but to make it clear that something "runs" this chain
```

I'm unable to think of any "generic" way of creating these components where this chaining can be "defined" at compile time to restrict which components can be wired with others (i.e., the input/output types should match). Thus `c1` can only be followed by `c2` but not by `c3` - but nothing can be chained after `c3`.

Is this even possible? Anything to get it close enough?

(For the curious minded: Trying to achieve a similar "composability" that Finagle offers in the world of Scala)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of generics is a bit confusing to me, since it doesn't look like you've made clear the difference between type parameter *variables* and the concrete types you plug into them.  Not to mention your use of non-TS terms like `val` and `None`.  Anyway, the following is something that compiles and *might* give you the sort of behavior you're looking for:

```
type NotNever<T, Y=T, N=never> = [T] extends [never] ? N : Y;

// just create types, don't worry about implementation
declare class BaseComponent<In, Out, Xin=never, Xout=never> {
  // make BaseComponent depend structurally on type parameters
  i: In;
  o: Out;
  xi: Xin;
  xo: Xout;

  // andThen() is generic, and only accepts the right kind of other component
  // only callable if Xin and Xout are *not* never
  andThen<Yin, Yout>(
    this: NotNever<Xin | Xout, this>,
    c: BaseComponent<Xin, Xout, Yin, Yout>
  ): BaseComponent<In, Out, Yin, Yout>;

  // run() is only callable if Xin and Xout *are* never
  run(this: BaseComponent<In, Out, never, never>): void;
}

// create some concrete subclasses where parameters are set with string literal types
class Component1 extends BaseComponent<'In', 'Out', 'Xin', 'Xout'> { }
class Component2 extends BaseComponent<'Xin', 'Xout', 'Yin', 'Yout'> { }
class Component3 extends BaseComponent<'Yin', 'Yout'> { }
```

You can see how it works:

```
const c1 = new Component1();
const c2 = new Component2();
const c3 = new Component3();

c1.andThen(c1); // error
c1.andThen(c2); // okay
c1.andThen(c3); // error
c1.run(); // error

c2.andThen(c1); // error
c2.andThen(c2); // error
c2.andThen(c3); // okay
c2.run(); // error

c3.andThen(c1); // error
c3.andThen(c2); // error
c3.andThen(c3); // error
c3.run(); // okay

const chain = c1.andThen(c2).andThen(c3) // BaseComponent<'In', 'Out', never, never>;
chain.run(); // okay
```

I think this is similar to what you want?  Hope that helps; good luck!

---

EDIT:  Another way to do the same thing but without worrying about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) is the following:

```
// one base class for the end of the chain
declare class EndComponent<In, Out> {
  i: In;
  o: Out;
  run(): void;
}

// another base class for intermediate parts of the chain
declare class PipeComponent<In, Out, Xin, Xout> {
  i: In;
  o: Out;
  xi: Xin;
  xo: Xout;
  // andThen() is overloaded 
  andThen<Yin, Yout>(
    c: PipeComponent<Xin, Xout, Yin, Yout>
  ): PipeComponent<In, Out, Yin, Yout>;
  andThen(c: EndComponent<Xin, Xout>): EndComponent<In, Out>;
}

class Component1 extends PipeComponent<'In', 'Out', 'Xin', 'Xout'> { }
class Component2 extends PipeComponent<'Xin', 'Xout', 'Yin', 'Yout'> { }
class Component3 extends EndComponent<'Yin', 'Yout'> { }
```

The rest should behave as before.  Good luck again!

Comment: This is interesting. Especially the one with `polymorphic this` and `conditional types`. The EDIT case is rather intriguing too. Can definitely play around with this. `None` was alluded as a "custom type" not part of TS. Fixed the `val` to `const` too - forgot about that. But thank you for these suggestions and taking the time on your part to help out. This _might_ just work :)

But why String literals in params and not actual types? @jcalz

Comment: String literals: no reason other than convenience.  If you have real types, you should be able to use them in their place.

Comment: the second implementation seems would need a `run` method, no?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got:

```
class Component<T, U> {
    constructor(private t: T, private u: U) {}
    andThen<V>(component: Component<U, V>): Component<U, V> {
        // implement andThen
        return component;
    }
    static run<T>(component: Component<T, null>) {
        // implement run
    }
}

type A = 'a'; const a: A = 'a';
type B = 'b'; const b: B = 'b';
type C = 'c'; const c: C = 'c';

const c1 = new Component<A, B>(a, b);
const c2 = new Component<B, C>(b, c);
const c3 = new Component<C, null>(c, null);

c2.andThen(c1); // TS2345: A is not assignable to B
Component.run(c1.andThen(c2)); // TS2345: Component<B,C> not assignable to Component<B,null>
Component.run(c1.andThen(c2).andThen(c3));
```

*I've simplified the code: `<Xin, Xout, Yin, Yout>` → `<T,U>` but that's easily adaptable.*

The *chain* is typed as expected. At runtime, `Component<...,X>.andThen(Component<Y,...>)` is detected as invalid (first `TS2345`).

Slight refactoring, it is not the chain itself (ie, `Component`) that invokes `.run` - after half an hour, I couldn't find a way to detect, at compile time and not runtime, that `.run` was invoked by a `Component<..., null>` (ie last component of a chain).

Instead, I put the `run` as a static method of the `Component` and it only takes as an input a *last component*. The usage is demonstrated in the last two lines

Last but not least, the class has been kept very general and polymorphic, so as many components can be chained!

```
(new Component<'a', 'b'>('a', 'b'))
.andThen(new Component<'b', 'c'>('b', 'c'))
.andThen(new Component<'c', 'd'>('c', 'd'))
.andThen(new Component<'d', 'e'>('d', 'e'))
.andThen(new Component<'e', 'f'>('e', 'f'))
.andThen(new Component<'f', 'g'>('f', 'g'))
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.